# Selecting data from one table or another in multiple queries PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

The easiest way to ask my question is with a Hypothetical Scenario.

Lets say we have 3 tables.   Singapore_Prices, Produce_val, and Bosses_unreasonable_demands.

So Prices is a pretty simple table.  Item column containing a name, and a Price column containing a number.

Produce_Val is also simple 2 column table.   Type column containing what type the produce is (Fruit or veggie)  and then Name column (Tomato, pineapple, etc.)

The Bosses_unreasonable_demands only contains one column, Fruit, which CAN contain the names of some fruits.

OK?   Ok.

SO, My boss wants me to write a query that returns the prices for every fruit in his unreasonable demands table.   Simple enough.   BUT, if he doesn't have any entries in his table, he just wants me to output the prices of ALL fruits that exist in produce_val.

Now, assuming I don't know where the DBA who designed this silly hypothetical system lives (and therefore can't get him to fix this), our query would look like this:

```
if <Logic to determine if Bosses demands are empty>
Then
select Item, Price
from Singapore_Prices
where Item in (select Fruit from Bosses_Unreasonable_demands)
Else
select Item, Price
from Singapore_Prices
where Item in (select Name from Produce_val where type = 'Fruit')
end if;
```

(Well, we'd select those into a variable, and then output the variable, probably with bulk-collect shenanigans, but that's not important)

Which works.   It is entirely functional, and won't be slow, even if we extend it out to 2000 other stores other than Singapore.  (Well, no slower than anything else that touches 2000 some tables)    BUT, I'm still doing two different select statements that are practically identical.  My Comp Sci teacher rolls in their grave every time my fingers hit ctrl-V.    I can cut this code in half and only do one select statement.   I KNOW I can.

I just have no earthly idea how.    I can't use cursors as an in statement, I can't use nested tables or varrays, I can't use cleverly crafted strings, I... I just... I don't know.   I don't know how to do this.   Is there a way?  Does it exist?

Or do I have to copy/paste forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be dynamic SQL, because you can't parameterize table or column names.

You will have a SQL query template, have a logic to determine tables and columns that you want to query, then blend them together and execute.

Another aproach, (still a lot of ctrl-v like code) is to use set construction UNION ALL:

```
select 1st query where boss_condition
union all
select 2nd query where not boss_condition
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nested tables.  Assume you have a schema-level nested table type FRUIT_NAME_LIST (defined using `CREATE TYPE`).

```
SELECT fruit
  BULK COLLECT INTO my_fruit_name_list
  FROM bosses_unreasonable_demands
;

IF my_fruit_name_list.count = 0 THEN
  SELECT name
    BULK COLLECT INTO my_fruit_name_list
    FROM produce_val
    WHERE type='Fruit'
  ;
END IF;

SELECT item, price
  FROM singapore_prices
  WHERE item MEMBER OF my_fruit_name_list
;
```

(or, `WHERE item IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(CAST(my_fruit_name_list AS fruit_name_list))` if you like that better)

Comment: These sounded like exactly what I wanted, so I gave them a shot.

Your first solution provided an error "Local collection types not allowed in SQL Statements"

The second was an Invalid Data Type error.

Comment: By "a nested table type" I mean one at the schema level, defined using `CREATE TYPE`, not one declared in a PL/SQL block.  It sounds like you did the latter.  I will edit to clarify (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT s.*, 'BOSS' AS FRUIT_SOURCE
          FROM BOSSES_UNREASONABLE_DEMANDS b
          INNER JOIN SINGAPORE_FRUIT_LIST s
            ON s.ITEM = b.FRUIT
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS BOSS_COUNT
                        FROM BOSSES_UNREASONABLE_DEMANDS)) x
  UNION ALL
       (SELECT s.*, 'NORMAL' AS FRUIT_SOURCE
          FROM PRODUCE_VAL p
          INNER JOIN SINGAPORE_FRUIT_LIST s
            ON (s.ITEM = p.NAME AND
                s.TYPE = 'Fruit')
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS BOSS_COUNT
                        FROM BOSSES_UNREASONABLE_DEMANDS)) n
  WHERE (BOSS_COUNT > 0 AND FRUIT_SOURCE = 'BOSS') OR
        (BOSS_COUNT = 0 AND FRUIT_SOURCE = 'NORMAL')
```

Share and enjoy.